# Cordova: Sending Data via TCP

Tags: javascript, android, sockets, cordova, tcp

I'm trying to send data between an Android application created with Cordova and an application running on a Windows machine; the application on the Windows machine requires TCP protocol. I've worked with Cordova before, but I haven't used many plugins for Cordova--and therefore I've had difficulty setting up plugins--and socket programming isn't familiar ground for me.

Anywho, I read that I could use chrome.socket with Cordova somewhere, so I've tried doing that, but I'm only receiving errors indicating that "chrome" is undefined.

I first installed the plugin via command line: cordova plugin add org.chromium.socket

It then appeared in the plugins directory of my Cordova application.

Then, I included the following code in my application:

```
var dataString = "Message to send";
var data = new Uint8Array(dataString.length);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     data[i] = dataString.charCodeAt(i);
}

try {        
    chrome.socket.create("tcp", function(createInfo) {
        var socketId = createInfo.socketId;
        try {
            chrome.socket.connect(socketId, hostname, port, function(result) {
                if (result === 0) {
                    chrome.socket.write(socketId, data, function(writeInfo) {
                        chrome.socket.read(socketId, 1000, function(readInfo) {
                        });
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("CONNECT FAILED");
                }
            });
        }
        catch (err)
        {
            alert("ERROR! " + err);
        }
    });
}
catch (err)
{
    alert("ERROR! " + err);
}
```

I get the error alert every time, because chrome.socket is undefined; this makes me think that I did not set this up correctly. At any rate, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since, I don't see any immediate issues with code. can you please try the following?
Just for shits and giggles, what happens if you set your hostname as www.google.com and port as 80 or 443?
Also, what is the name/nature of the windows application?
Can you make sure you can connect to that tcp port using netcat or such from an external machine?

Comment: I'll try that first thing tomorrow. However, the problem isn't connecting to the TCP port--if I try to send data through with other, non-Cordova applications, the connection runs just fine--the issue is that I'm getting a "function create of undefined" error. The application doesn't seem to be recognizing chrome.socket/it hasn't been imported properly (Even though I installed it via the written command line statement).

Comment: @JoshuaJennings Why don't u try out [socket.io](http://socket.io). It is not that difficult to use and you do not need any socket programming Knowledge. FYI all HTTP request method(POST, GET) internally use TCP protocol as their transport mechanism.

Comment: @JoshuaJennings As per my understandings you need to **configure** your **webserver** to handle chrome sockets(chrome.sockets.tcpServer). Adding **only** the client in your phonegap/cordova app your code is **not** going to work.

Comment: The issue is that I'm working with existing proprietary software on the receiving machine; its documentation states that it just needs to receive messages over TCP protocol and via a specific port. I do understand that both sides need to be configured properly for this to work, but as I mentioned, I think the most immediate issue is that the library/plugin isn't being recognized (I also tried implementing socket.io earlier, and its tools weren't recognized either). I think I need a cohesive guide to setting thins up with these tools.

Comment: Were you able to send info over the TCP after all?

Comment: Were you able to send info over the TCP after all?

Comment: @JoshuaJennings could you find some way to send data between cordova apps?